# Camera VC0706 send image save to pc

Tags: arduino-mega, camera

i'm working on project now,
i need to save picture from camera VC0706 serial camera in specific folder on my PC, i found a tutorial (indonesian tutorial), thath give me code to use the camera, but they not tell me how to save the picture,
basically i need this image show on android phone, but i don't have money to buy a paid web server that can store image, so i want to use local webserver (PhpMyadmin using Xammpp) and call the image from **htdoc** folder, so i can show the image on android phoe

here is the code

```
 #include <Adafruit_VC0706.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>      

// Software serial & camera instance
SoftwareSerial cameraconnection = SoftwareSerial(2,3); // RX, TX
Adafruit_VC0706 cam = Adafruit_VC0706(&cameraconnection);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Program Test Camera");

  // Try to locate the camera
  if (cam.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Camera Terbaca");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Camera Tidak Terbaca !!!");
    return;
  }

  // Set ukuran gambar  
  cam.setImageSize(VC0706_640x480);   // Vga
  //cam.setImageSize(VC0706_320x240); // Qvga
  //cam.setImageSize(VC0706_160x120); // QQVGA
  // Tunggu 3 detik untuk capture
  Serial.println("Picture in 3 seconds ...");
  delay(3000);

  if (! cam.takePicture()) 
    Serial.println("Failed to capture!");
  else 
    Serial.println("Capture Gambar OK ");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: why don't you start with the example code that is included with the library?

Comment: @jsotola library of what?

Comment: The examples of the Adafruit_VC0706 library. It shows, how to save an image to a SD card. For sending it over wifi, you first need a wifi module. You can buy an ESP8266 module for that, though it might be a better idea to directly use an ESP instead of the Mega